# moving coordinates in a grid

Tags: python, grid

These are my global variables

```
number_black_balls= 8
black_balls=[[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1], [6,6], [6,5], [5,5], [5,6]]

number_white_balls= 8
white_balls=[[6,0], [6,1], [5,1], [5,0], [0,6], [0,5], [1,5], [1,6]]

number_red_balls= 13
red_balls=[[1,3], [2,2], [2,3], [2,4], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], [3,4], [3,5], [4,2], [4,3], [4,4], [5,3]]

## Movements: ##
column= ["   ", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
dict_movement= {"up":[-1,0],"down":[1,0],"left":[0,-1],"right":[0,1]}  ##direction in which I'm going
##########################
```

And here are the functions:

```
def grid():
    res=[0]*7
    for i in range(7):
        res[i]= ["*"]*7            
    return res
    print (res[i]," ",end="\n")


def show_grid(g):
    print()
    for i in column:
        print(i, end="  ")
    print()
    print("   -----------------------  ")
    for i, line in enumerate(g, 1):
        print (i,"| ", "  ".join(line), " |",i)
    print("   -----------------------  ")

    for i in column:
        print(i, end="  ")
    print("\n")

def balls_location(g):
    for r in red_balls:
        g[r[0]][r[1]]="R"
    for b in white_balls:
        g[b[0]][b[1]]="B"
    for n in black_balls:
        g[n[0]][n[1]]="N"
    return g

def initGame():          
    g=grid()
    g=balls_location(g)
    return g

g=initgame()
show_grid(g)
```

How do I move the pieces knowing that I can only move if there's nothing behind the piece. It's a two players game. The game has three names (Akiba, Kuba, traboulet) if you want to check the rules.

the end result should be like this:

```
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
   -----------------------  
1 |  N  N  *  *  *  B  B  | 1
2 |  N  N  *  R  *  B  B  | 2
3 |  *  *  R  R  R  *  *  | 3
4 |  *  R  R  R  R  R  *  | 4
5 |  *  *  R  R  R  *  *  | 5
6 |  B  B  *  R  *  N  N  | 6
7 |  B  B  *  *  *  N  N  | 7
   -----------------------  
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7 

### the command
>>> player 1 > 1(column) 1(row) down(direction)
```

and it should look like this afterwards.

```
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
   -----------------------  
1 |  *  N  *  *  *  B  B  | 1
2 |  N  N  *  R  *  B  B  | 2
3 |  N  *  R  R  R  *  *  | 3
4 |  *  R  R  R  R  R  *  | 4
5 |  *  *  R  R  R  *  *  | 5
6 |  B  B  *  R  *  N  N  | 6
7 |  B  B  *  *  *  N  N  | 7
   -----------------------  
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7 

>>> player 2>
```

Comment: To anyone not familiar with the game, this question is going to require some research, possibly some language translation, and understanding how to use your functions, most users are not going to take the time to research these. Your question may get more attention and feedback if you can give examples of how to run your code and where code for moving the pieces might go. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Alright, I translated the text and added the function that would print my grid, the movements are still a problem and I hope that someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very "hacky" and messy way of doing it, here is just an example of what I got to "work":

```
def players_move(r, c, dir):
    if dir == 'down':
        if g[r+1][c] == '*':
            for b in black_balls:
                if b[1] == 0:
                    black_balls[b[0]][0] += 1
        g[r-1][c-1] = '*'

g=initGame()
show_grid(g)

players_move(1, 1, "down")
balls_location(g)
show_grid(g)
```

This gives the after-result you showed.

And since you have a much better understanding of your code and the logic involved you can probably improve this a lot.